# SQL - Get Highest Value For Positive And Lowest Value For Negative

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I Use this code for get AVG number from my oracle database server and now I need code to get Number with highest if Positive And Lowest if Negative How can I do?:

```
Select AVG(EAX_T) AS EAX, AVG(EAI_T) AS EAI, H 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE SR = ? AND TO_DATE(DATEADD) = ?
GROUP BY H 
ORDER BY H ASC
```

The Data can be Like this :

```
SR   |H   |EAX_T   |EAI_T
45   |8   |-3      |0
45   |8   |-2      |0
98   |8   |8       |0
98   |8   |2       |0
106  |8   |0       |-1
106  |8   |0       |-9
```

I want sql Query for select row Group by H And SR if EAI_T OR EAX_T is Positive Number select Row With Highest And If EAI_T or EAX_T is negative Select The Lowest, If

```
45   |8   |-3      |0
45   |8   |-2      |0
```

SELECT ROW That Have -3
And If

```
98   |8   |8       |0
98   |8   |2       |0
```

SELECT Row That Have 8

Update :
I have 46 milion row The H is ref to Hour , so in one day i have 1000 devices and i need get avg of data in H and if it's Higher than 0 get Highest number in day and if lowest than 0 get Lowest rows to make my another table with this data , so SR ref to device Id and in my new table ill pick  data that I found and make H1 , H2 , .... for devices

Comment: Can you give more detail about get Number with highest if Positive And Lowest if Negative?

Comment: @劉鎮瑲 Post updated, Sorry for my english

Comment: What result you looking for  when running your code?

Comment: @劉鎮瑲I need pick row with Highest if positive or Lowest if negative for each SR

Comment: Are you mean :`select S ,
case 
when AVG(EAX_T) >0 then Max(EAX_T) 
when AVG(EAX_T) <0 then Min(EAX_T) end as EAX from TABLENAME group by S`

Comment: I suggest you give the data you have and the result you want in your post. It could help more people know what you want.

Comment: Thanks i want something like that @劉鎮瑲

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: You are showing sample data. As this data contains multiple rows per H, I assume this is the data in the table, not the data your query produces. Then you are showing desired results. But these results show one EAX_T and one EAI_T value per SR and H. There is no average. So, why do you use `AVG` in your query? Do you want some average or not? Please update your request to clarify this.

Comment: On a side note: This `TO_DATE(DATEADD) = ?` looks bad. This suggests that `DATEADD` is a string containing a date that you must convert to a date in order to compare it with a variable. You should not store dates as strings in the database, but use the appropriate data type, which is `DATE`. Then, when applying `TO_DATE` on a string, state the format that must be used (e.g. `TO_DATE(datestring, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`), because otherwise you let the DBMS guess, and whether it guesses right or comes up with a wrong result or even crashes depends on session settings.

Comment: the code work and I have no problem with it , the time you say its right but i need multi date time so for my other side to have less code i use this @ThorstenKettner

Comment: From your new description: **1.** Your table contains multiple rows per device (SR) and hour (H). **2.** Per device you want the average values of EAX_T and EAI_T per hour. **3.** If the average EAX_T for an hour is negative you want the minimum EAX_T of that hour. If the average EAX_T for an hour is positive you want the maximum EAX_T of that hour. Same for EAI_T. **If this is so, then 劉鎮瑲's query does what you want and forpas' query does not.**

Comment: Here is another example: 107|8|1|-1, 107|8|1|-1, 107|8|1|-1, 107|8|-3|2. The desired result would be 107|8|0|-1. 0 for EAX_T, because 1+1+1-3=0, so you want neither the minimum nor the maximum. -1 for EAI_T, because -1-1-1+2=-1, which is negative, so you want the minimum. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the question owner using AVG in the code. I guess the owner want highest or lowest number according to the AVG(EAX_T) positive or negative group by SR and H.

Using CASE when AVG bigger than 0 get MAX , smaller than 0 get Min, equal 0 give 0.

```
 select SR,H , 
    case  
    when AVG(EAX_T) >0 then Max(EAX_T)  
    when AVG(EAX_T) <0 then Min(EAX_T) else 0 end as EAX, 
    case  
    when AVG(EAI_T) >0 then Max(EAI_T)  
    when AVG(EAI_T) <0 then Min(EAI_T) else 0 end as EAI from TABLENAME group by SR,H
```

I think the owner data just one sign in a group of SR and H.  I also give @forpas upvote because I think his answer match the owner thought.

Comment: @劉鎮瑲 Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use MAX() window function:

```
select distinct t.*
from (
  select t.sr, t.h,
    sign(eax_t) * max(abs(eax_t)) over (partition by sr, h) eax_t,
    sign(eai_t) * max(abs(eai_t)) over (partition by sr, h) eai_t
  from tablename t
) t
order by t.sr, t.h
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0a158b4b50efe85fd4ac41ab198c2380).
Results:

```
>  SR |  H | EAX_T | EAI_T
> --: | -: | ----: | ----:
>  45 |  8 |    -3 |     0
>  98 |  8 |     8 |     0
> 106 |  8 |     0 |    -9
```